# Missing recommended icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, validation, archive

I have been trying to validate my app, but 2 yellow warning keep appearing each time I do. The one in the title is the first, and the second is similar, but saying I don't have a '152x152' icon for iPad. I have already dragged and dropped all the icons into into "AppIcon" in the Images.xcassets file, and there are no spaces left, and yet this error still appears. How can I solve this problem?

I have looked at the other similar questions, but they don't offer solutions to my problem.

A screenshot of my Images.xcassets file.

[image]

[Link to full size image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM0rB.png)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the assets file and the inspector of those files.

Comment: Original post edited :)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I thought so.

In the assets file where it says "50pt" then this is a 50 **point** sized image.

The 1X image needs to be 50x50. The 2X image needs to be 100x100. The 3X image would then need to be 150x150.

I'm guessing that you're using the same image for the 1X, 2X and 3X.

In your screenshot you have selected the 50pt 2X image and it shows "50x50" in the inspector. This should be 100x100.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I'm using the same size for all the scales. Aw man, that's gonna be a lot of resizing! But thanks for the solution - With any luck this will solve the problem :)

Comment: @IsaacA which OS are you building for? You can remove iOS6 and lower if your target OS is 7. I'd recommend aiming for 7 as a lowest if possible.

Comment: @IsaacA remember to accept and upvote the answer if it fixes your problem. :)